# writing movie using GPUImagemovieWriter crashes the app

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

I am using GPUImageMovie to Filter and save movie in my device but my App is crashing at

**dispatch_sync(videoProcessingQueue, block);**

at **GPUImageOutput.m** File. When I debug it It breaks at

**self.movieWriter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL: movieURL, size: CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height))**

Here is my Code :

```
var paths: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let  filePath = paths[0].stringByAppendingString("/image.mov")
        let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
        let videoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
        //CGAffineTransform videoTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.ValueOrientation);
        self.movieFile1 = GPUImageMovie(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
        self.movieFile1.runBenchmark = true
       // self.filterExport = self.filterobject
        self.movieFile1.addTarget(self.pixellateFilter)
        self.pixellateFilter.removeAllTargets()
        let filteredFile: String = paths[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("/MovieFiltered.m4v")
        unlink((filteredFile as NSString).UTF8String)
        let movieURL: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filteredFile)
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(filteredFile)
            print("File removed")
        }catch{
            print("Not Removed")
        }
        
        self.movieWriter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL: movieURL, size: CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height))
        self.pixellateFilter.addTarget(self.movieWriter)
        self.movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = true
        self.movieFile1.audioEncodingTarget = self.movieWriter
        self.movieFile1.enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter(self.movieWriter)
        self.movieWriter.startRecording()
        self.movieFile1.startProcessing()
        weak var weakSelf = self
        self.movieWriter.completionBlock = {() -> Void in
          print("Recording done")
            weakSelf!.movieWriter.finishRecording()
        
}
```

I used to many codes apart from this but always app crashes on same point. Please give me solution. I used this code too.. Same error coming...

```
var paths: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let  filePath = paths[0].stringByAppendingString("/image.mov")
        movieFile = GPUImageMovie(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
        pixellateFilter = GPUImagePixellateFilter()
        movieFile.addTarget(pixellateFilter)
        
        
        let pathToMovie : String = paths[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("filtered.mov")
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(pathToMovie)
            print("File removed")
        }catch{
            print("Not Removed")
        }

        unlink((pathToMovie as NSString).UTF8String)
        let movieURL: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(pathToMovie)
        movieWriter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL: movieURL, size: CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0))
        pixellateFilter.addTarget(movieWriter)
        movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = true
        movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter
        movieFile.enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter(movieWriter)
        movieWriter.startRecording()
        movieFile.startProcessing()
        
        
        self.movieWriter.completionBlock = {() -> Void in
            print("Recording done")
            self.pixellateFilter.removeTarget(self.movieWriter)
            self.movieWriter.finishRecording()
        }
```

Comment: Actually I am getting Nil;l Value in Context also

Answer (score 0):

Very little mistake done by me i was forget to write

**movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = nil**

Because My video was not containing sound. Yup..